# Python basic question which i really cant understand the logic

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
def sum_five(l):
    return sum(num for num in l if num > 5)
```

```
#desired outcome:
#sum_five([1, 5, 20, 30, 4, 9, 18]) ➞ 77
#sum_five([1, 2, 3, 4]) ➞ 0
#sum_five([10, 12, 28, 47, 55, 100]) ➞ 252
```

gotten this as a solution. The question is to loop through a list and sum up those that are less than 5. This is the cleanest and shortest answer which i really loved to learn. Can anyone explain in very simple English to me what does the num for num in l if num > 5 really means?
And give me more examples to understand that logic so i can next time apply it? PS: i can do the outcome using for loop and if statement already, i just want to learn how to use this one liner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as `Generator Expression` which gives you another list which means like this:

**FOR** any element which we call it `num`, in the list which we call it `l`, if this element(`num`) is greater than 5, take it and put it in result list.

For example for `[1,2,3,4]` there is no number greater than 5, so the result is `[]` which has the summation equal to zero.

Another example is `[1,5,20,30,4,9,18]` which has the result equal to `[20,30,9,18]` which has the summation equal to `20+30+9+18 = 77`

Comment: It's not a list comprehension, it's a generator expression. You can tell by the lack of square brackets.

Comment: it's good to know, thnx @ShadowRanger

Answer (score -1):

The list comprehension -- any list comprehension -- can be written as a for loop remembering that it returns a list (meaning you don't have to write the part that assigns the result to a list which in this case I've called `out`). That's a good thing because that list you are taking the sum of and returning that result instead.

```
out = []
def sum_five(l):
    for num in l:
        if num > 5:
            out.append(num)
        else:
            continue
    return sum(out)
```

The general form a list comprehension is worth going into more. But I'm going to strip out some of the code to this for clarity

```
for num in l:
        if num > 5:
            num
```

Goes to this:

```
for num in l if num > 5:
            num
```

And then to this:

```
num for num in l if num > 5:
```

We don't need that colon at the end and the whole thing gets put in braces because that's what specifies a list is getting returned. That leaves us with:

```
[num for num in l if num > 5]
```

You then take the sum of that list:

```
sum([num for num in l if num > 5])
```

You'll notice the formatting is a bit different than for the loop. If it was just a long no one would use it.

Comment: The OP's case is not a list comprehension, it's a generator expression. You can tell by the lack of square brackets.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But, from what I've noticed, new people often get things just plain wrong. The OP is saying they don't the basic logic. To me, that means a generator was not intended. And if turns out that was the case -- editing the question and answer will be in order.